# How to refresh datagridview in Windows Smart Device

Tags: c#, winforms, smart-device

How to refresh the data grid view in windows form in a smart device that i am using, Cipher Lab 30 .

I already have used datagridview.Refresh() , and datagridview.Update() after i deleted or insert some rows in data grid view. Nothing happens. But the SQL Works

Comment: Wait ill check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting a `DataSource` you can use `Gridview.Databind();` to rebind the source

Or you can use [`DataGridView.Invalidate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.invalidate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Wait ill check it out bro! Thanks! .

Comment: @Dalyun If you found my answer useful, please upvote it. If it solves your problem, please mark as answer, thanks. :)